# Is the Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 STM compatible with the Canon 4000d?

Tags: lens, lens-mount

I'm a photography enthusiast and I'm looking to buy a canon 4000d and a lens for it, but am not sure whether it's compatible with a canon 4000d or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each camera manufacturer has a lens mount designed to match their cameras with their lenses.

The original Canon autofocus lens mount (1987 and on) is the EF mount. *Every SLR/DSLR* Canon autofocus body made since then can attach to EF lenses.

When digital was introduced, it used a smaller sensor size than the size of film (this is the difference between APS-C sized sensors and "full frame" sensors). Lenses designed for this smaller format are designated EF-S. EF-S lenses, due to the smaller image circle they project, will not fit Full Frame cameras but will fit APS-C.

For this reason, a Full Frame camera like the 5D mark 3 has the listed mount of "EF" while your 4000D is listed as "EF-S".

What is not immediately apparent is the fact that **any** EF-S camera can *also* use EF lenses.

Essentially, you can use *any* Canon SLR Autofocus lens. If you are shopping third party lenses, make sure they say "For Canon", "For Canon EF", or "For Canon EF-S". As long as they list that they are "For Canon," it'll attach.

Side note: Canon has lenses designed for their mirrorless cameras designated EF-M and RF mount. Neither of these will fit your camera. Stick to EF and EF-S.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer!

Comment: "Every Canon autofocus body made since then can attach to EF lenses." Well, EOS EF-M and EOS R bodies can not *directly* attach to an EF lens.

Comment: @MichaelC yea, I caught myself on that one in my side note. Adjusted that paragraph to align as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is compatible with any EF or EF-S lens mount. The 4000D is an EF-S mount.

Comment: Thank you for the help!